# Executing script or comands in diferent console (CYRADM)

Tags: scripting, console, sh, postfix-mta, cyrus

Thanks in adviance:

Hello
im trying to execute diferent commands extracted from other stable script used to extract the commands we have to execute in cyradm console
i do

```
[root@srvmtrx9870]# sh addFolder2Mailbox.sh > commands.sh
```

this generates a script .sh that i cant never execute in the cyradm console (ever fails) not find the command 
i tried many things but i started to think is impossible doing with simple shell or bash scripts

example:

```
 localhost>  ./commands.sh
    ./commands.sh: línea 1: cm: no se encontró la orden
    ./commands.sh: línea 2: sam: no se encontró la orden
    ./commands.sh: línea 3: cm: no se encontró la orden
    ./commands.sh: línea 4: sam: no se encontró la orden
    ./commands.sh: línea 5: cm: no se encontró la orden
    ./commands.sh: línea 6: sam: no se encontró la orden
    ./commands.sh: línea 7: quit: no se encontró la orden
```

when i put only the command works

```
localhost> cm
usage: createmailbox [--partition partition] mailbox [partition]
cat commands.sh
cm 'user/'
sam 'user/'  lrswipcda
cm 'user/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
sam 'user/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  lrswipcda
cm 'user/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
sam 'user/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  lrswipcda
quit
```

BASH IS SHELL (OR THAT SEEMS)

```
localhost> echo $BASH
/bin/sh
```

AND IM ROOT

```
localhost> whoami
root
```

the script has the proper rights 
(i edited some text changing personal info by xxxxxx)
anyone knows how to execute external scripts in cyradm console?? , i tried many thing , but nothing worked for me ..

Comment: Seems when executing bash scripts changes bash and not found the commands of cyradm console...???  Any idea of switch console?? Or execute in same console a file with lines of commands..  Is for automatic tasks of backup....

Comment: https://cyrusimap.org/docs/cyrus-imapd/2.2.13p1/man/cyradm.1.php

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Need IMAP password , please input password"
{
cyradm --user mailadmin localhost << EOT
cm
sam
EOT
} >> error.out
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Comment: The cyradm is a bit weird... first try to execute as perl, and if not find then tries with bash , the problem was i cannot pass any commands to this console ... this was the only way to make commands be executed on this console .